# Ran Gzip command and broke my site, need help with reverse command

Tags: apache-2.2, gzip

In trying to back up a website on an apache server this am I ran the following:

## gzip -r /var/www/httpd/vhosts/mysite.com/ mysite.gzip

Trying to backup the path to the gzip file.  Howvever, after completeion i go to the website url and get the apache welcome screen.

What happened? Is there a way to easily reverse this?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in `find /var/www/httpd/vhosts/mysite.com/`; do gunzip $file; done
```

You gziped everything in your htdocs root into file.gz file2.gz and it probably errored when it didn't find the file.gzip

Comment: +1 - better answer than mine. I saw that he'd got the arguments the wrong way around but didn't realise it would have globbed it. He may have gzipped the directory rather than everything in it?

Comment: Thank you, apparently it didn't create the file mysite.gzip but instead just replaced all of the files with gzip versions of themselves.  Is there a way to reverse that?

Comment: my command will reverse it for all the files

Comment: is there any chance I can unzip those Mike?

Comment: His command is in the answer.

Comment: This command: gunzip $file  that gives me /../ is a directory ignored

Comment: That's probably done it, but if not, try: `find /var/www/httpd/vhosts/site.com/ -name \*.gz -exec gunzip '{}' \;`

Comment: you are not running the WHOLE COMMAND.. its starts with for.. ends with done

Comment: @Martin For future reference, gzip only compresses **one file at a time**.  If you want to archive the entire directory into a single file, use `tar czf file.tar.gz /var/www/httpd/vhosts/mysite.com/` and be sure you have the .tar.gz file first because tar will happily overwrite whatever file you tell it to archive everything in.

Comment: That last command looks to be doing it.  Thank you soooo much.

Comment: Thanks mike, I get what you mean now.  James' command looks to be working as well.

Answer (score 0):

You got your arguments the wrong way around. What's the output of ls -al /var/www/httpd/vhosts/mysite.com/? It might not be a big issue.

Comment: It lists the contents of the directory.

Comment: I know what the command does, I asked for the output not the purpose of the command. Basically I wanted to know what was still in the directory, but see @Mike's answer.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's too late, but maybe type "man gzip" before running the command?

Comment: To be fair, man gzip isn't too helpful. There's no examples for basic usage and it only states "gzip [ -acdfhlLnNrtvV19 ] [-S suffix] [ name ...  ]" which isn't obvious.